# Trouble installing Gitlab on CentOS 6.5

Tags: postgresql, centos, gitlab

I have attempted, several times to install Gitlab on my CentOS 6.5 VPS as per the instructions on the [Official page](https://about.gitlab.com/downloads/#centos) and every time, it fails during the "gitlab-ctl reconfigure" stage of installation. I tried googling around and looking in other questions on here without much luck.

Error is as follows:

```
* execute[create gitlab database user] action run
================================================================================
Error executing action `run` on resource 'execute[create gitlab database user]'
================================================================================


---- Begin output of /opt/gitlab/embedded/bin/psql --port 5432 -d template1 -c "CREATE            USER gitlab" ----
STDOUT:
STDERR: psql: could not connect to server: No such file or directory
        Is the server running locally and accepting
        connections on Unix domain socket "/tmp/.s.PGSQL.5432"?
---- End output of /opt/gitlab/embedded/bin/psql --port 5432 -d template1 -c "CREATE  USER gitlab" ----
```

Comment: The default value that can be overriden is in https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/omnibus-gitlab/blob/master/files/gitlab-cookbooks/gitlab/attributes/default.rb#L189

Also, just for reference check this [issue](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/omnibus-gitlab/issues/129).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This might not be immediately related to GitLab, but to PostgreSQL itself.
See "[Chapter 17. Server Setup and Operation](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/server-start.html)", section "[Client Connection Problems](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/server-start.html#CLIENT-CONNECTION-PROBLEMS)":

> Alternatively, you'll get this when attempting Unix-domain socket communication to a local server:
>
> ```
> psql: could not connect to server: No such file or directory
>         Is the server running locally and accepting
>         connections on Unix domain socket "/tmp/.s.PGSQL.5432"?
> ```
>
> **The last line is useful in verifying that the client is trying to connect to the right place**.
> If there is in fact no server running there, the kernel error message will typically be either `Connection refused` or `No such file or directory`, as illustrated.
> (It is important to realize that Connection refused in this context does not mean that the server got your connection request and rejected it. That case will produce a different message, as shown in [Section 19.4](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/client-authentication-problems.html).)
> Other error messages such as `Connection timed out` might indicate more fundamental problems, like lack of network connectivity.

So make sure the database can start first.

The [OP Luke Usher](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3713421/luke-usher) confirms [in the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24353370/trouble-installing-gitlab-on-centos-6-5/24359472#comment37667489_24359472):

> The default PostgreSQL config included in gitlab was set to allocate more memory for **`shared_buffer`** than I have available.
>
> This was corrected by adding `postgresql['shared_buffers'] = "1024MB"` to `/etc/gitlab/gitlab.rb`.

Comment: The PostgreSQL process is running, so that was not the issue.

This did, however, lead me to the solution. The default PostgreSQL config included in gitlab was set to allocate more memory for shared_buffer than I have available. This was corrected by adding postgresql['shared_buffers'] = "1024MB" to /etc/gitlab/gitlab.rb.

Comment: @LukeUsher great! I have added your conclusion to the answer for more visibility.

Comment: Can you open an issue at https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/omnibus-gitlab/issues linking to this SO question? This should be added to the README.

Comment: @axil you need to add that comment to the question, or Luke (the OP) won't see it.